# To reorganize the table

Tags: r, transpose

I have a table as follows:

| LocationName | Date | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Booth | 2020-11-06 | 2021-03-08 |
| Charleswood | 2020-11-17 | 2021-03-08 |
| Fort Garry | 2017-08-29 | 2018-07-20 |

I want to get this table:

| LocationName | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Booth | 2020-11-06 |
| Booth | 2021-03-08 |
| Charleswood | 2020-11-17 |
| Charleswood | 2021-03-08 |
| Fort Garry | 2020-11-06 |
| Fort Garry | 2021-03-08 |

What do I do in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data in long format.

Using `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -LocationName, values_to = 'Date') %>%
  select(-name)

#  LocationName Date      
#  <chr>        <chr>     
#1 Booth        2020-11-06
#2 Booth        2021-03-08
#3 Charleswood  2020-11-17
#4 Charleswood  2021-03-08
#5 Fort Garry   2017-08-29
#6 Fort Garry   2018-07-20
```

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = 'LocationName', value.name = "Date")[, variable := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .(Date = unlist(.SD)),LocationName]
   LocationName       Date
1:        Booth 2020-11-06
2:        Booth 2021-03-08
3:  Charleswood 2020-11-17
4:  Charleswood 2021-03-08
5:   Fort Garry 2017-08-29
6:   Fort Garry 2018-07-20
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(LocationName = c("Booth", "Charleswood", "Fort Garry"
), Date = c("2020-11-06", "2020-11-17", "2017-08-29"), Date = c("2021-03-08", 
"2021-03-08", "2018-07-20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: @akrun Maybe we should close this post as a dupe.